# TeXnicCenter - open as PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, texnic-center

I have just spent some time installing TeXnicCenter and tried to configure it properly.  I'm almost there now!  The only issue I have is that every time I compile the document I'm working on as a PDF document, the document doesn't open directly in Adobe Reader X.  Instead I only get the "opening screen" of Adobe Reader X to pop up, meaning that I have to choose "Open file" and navigate to the proper folder where the document is saved to view it.  This is frustrating and time-consuming - especially if I want to check my progress often.  Is there any way I can configure this so that Adobe Reader X automatically opens the file I'm compiling, without me having to navigate to the proper folder?

Any help will be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is TeX related, you might have better luck posting in http://tex.stackexchange.com, StackExchange's TeX site.

You should look into [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43864/texniccenter-adobe-acrobat-10), pay special attention to the first two answers, they should work just fine.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In Adobe Reader X, go to `Edit -> Preferences`, there in category `general` there should be a checkbox `Enable protected mode at startup`. Uncheck this, exit adobe and try again. Does it work now?